# Fix joystick buttons only detect specific spots pressed

Tags: gaming, game-controller, joystick

I have a joystick. On top of the joystick there are 3 buttons perfectly accessable with my thumb. They are the most important buttons after the trigger, so I really want them to work. 2 of the buttons only detect when a certain part of the button is pressed. The buttons are basically useless in this condition. Could someone tell me how to fix the buttons? Is it even possible?

Joystick specs:

Microsoft Sidewinder Joystick (USB)

No force feedback or vibration

Bought used so maybe really old

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The switches are probably either dirty or wearing out.

First test would be to take it apart [best] or try to aim through the cracks [hit & miss] with a can of contact cleaner. Disconnect it from power first & allow plenty of time for it to dry out afterwards - at least an hour if you take it apart, a day if you don't.

If this doesn't improve things, then you can often get new switches - for mere pence if you can wait for them to ship from China. The main problem is how fiddly they are to actually change. Some skill &/or patience will be required.

Comment: Thanks Tetsujin, I'll try it today and update this post when results are ready!